# Problem with extending HBase Put

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I have a problem while trying to extend HBase Put class.

I have a code like this

```
public class HBasePut extends Put {  
    //here i define my own adds because i have only string "keys"  
    //so i dont have to use Bytes.toBytes() every time and so on 
}
```

But when testing these classes this code is OK:

```
Put p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes('row'));  
p.add(Bytes.toBytes('cf'), Bytes.toBytes('col'), Bytes.toBytes(1));
users.put(p);
```

But this one makes an exception after about 70 seconds of trying - RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException

```
HBasePut p = new HBasePut('row');  
p.add('cf', 'col', 1);
users.put(p);
```

So I tried to iterate over exceptions in RetriesExh... It tells me there is one exception but it is null...
I was looking at the code of Put, HTable and HConnection but I couldn't find any dependencies on writing exactly the class Put in HBase so I don't know why my HBasePut is not working.

Is it possible to extend Put somehow?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you look into your regionserver logs you will see an exception like "Can't find class ... HBasePut". So, HBase obviously transports a Put instance from client to server, but the server is unaware of your subclass and cannot process it.

I suggest refraining from subclassing and instead suggest to code a custom Util class which provides a static "add" method taking the Put instance and Strings as args and importing this method with a static import.

Comment: Yes, this was my second thought how to do it but I wanted to extend because this (Utils) way I lose the "fluid" pattern. $put->add('something')->add('and other')->...
But thank you very much - this is how I did it at the end.

Answer (score 0):

As zillion1 said, just use a static method:

```
public static void add(Put put, String col, String qual, String data)
{
  put.add(col.getBytes(), qual.getBytes(), data.getBytes());
}
```